# Copying a datatable to another datatable while changing the format of a column

Tags: vb.net, blueprism

I have a `DataTable` that I want to copy to another `DataTable`.. but the catch if that I want to change one of the columns to `Short Date` format (which is of type `String` in the original `Datatable`). I am able to add the columns from the original `Datatable` to the new one but when I try to set column format to `Date` type, it sets it to `Datetime` format. This causes a problem when copying data over from the original `Datatable` as the dates are not set correctly in the new table (i.e. **10/03/2018 00:00:00** changes to **10/01/2018 00:03:00**).

Any idea how I can resolve this issue? Or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

```
    Dim sColumn As String
    Dim dRow As DataRow

    For Each dC as DataColumn In dT.Columns
        dTRet.Columns.Add (dC.ColumnName)
    Next
    dTRet.Columns(ColName).DataType = GetType(Date)

    For Each row As DataRow in dT.Rows
        dRow = dTRet.NewRow
        For iC As Integer = 0 To dT.Columns.Count - 1
            sColumn = dT.Columns(iC).ColumnName

            If sColumn = ColName Then
                dRow(sColumn) = Date.ParseExact(row.Item(sColumn), DateFormat,
                                    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
                                    Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
            Else
                dRow(sColumn) = row.Item(sColumn)
            End If
        Next iC

        dTRet.Rows.Add (dRow)
    Next Row
```

`ColName`: holds the name of the column to change
`dT`: is the original `Datatable`
`dTRet`: is the new `Datatable`
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use `DateTime.ParseExact(row.Item(sColumn), "M/d/yyyy",                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: For OP & those coming from tags other than `blueprism`: this is likely due to a quirk of the Blue Prism implementation of VB datatypes, and there may not be much you can do to counteract it. IIRC, the Blue Prism-specific datatype `Date` is actually just a `DateTime` with a time value of 00:00:00.

Comment: It looks like the month value is ending up in the minute position, so that suggests that your format specifier is wrong and you are using a lower-case "m" (which represents minute) where you should be using an upper-case "M" (which represents month).  Is your `DateFormat` value "d/mm/yyyy" when it should be "d/MM/yyyy"?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: that's exactly what it seems to be doing (using month value as minutes). My `Dateformat` is **`dd/MM/yyyy`**. I have tried different `Dateformats` (all with **M**) but to no avail. I suspect **esqew** might have a point

Comment: @esqew: Thanks for the heads up. Does leave me in a precarious position. There is a work around where I can mimic what I am trying to do with code through an `Action` in BP `Object`. That seems to work but is much much slower